# Php insert into mysql with post variable function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to insert some datas in my DB with the following function (I don't get any errors but my datas don't get added in my DB) File name=insertuserdb:

```
<?php
function insertUser($U,$P,$E)
{
    $conn = connPDO();//*function to connect to my DB on the other file
    $query = ("INSERT INTO user (Username, Password, Email) VALUES (:User,:Pass,:Email)");
    $conn_prepare = $conn->prepare($query);
    $conn_prepare->execute(array( "User" => $U,"Pass" => $P,"Email" =>$E ));
    $id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    $conn_prepare->closeCursor();
    return $id;
}

?>
```

AND (my connection function (works/sorry for french)) file name=dbc3.php:

```
<?php

function connPDO()
{
    $PARAM_hote='localhost'; // le chemin vers le serveur
    $PARAM_port='';
    $PARAM_nom_bd='mygcpage'; // le nom de votre base de données
    $PARAM_utilisateur='root'; // nom d'utilisateur pour se connecter
    $PARAM_mot_passe=''; // mot de passe de l'utilisateur pour se connecter
    try {
        $connexion = new PDO('mysql:host='.$PARAM_hote.';port='.$PARAM_port.';dbname='.$PARAM_nom_bd, $PARAM_utilisateur, $PARAM_mot_passe);
        return $connexion;
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Erreur : '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
        echo 'N° : '.$e->getCode();
        die;
    }
}


$conn = connPDO();

if ($conn) {
    echo "connected";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not connect!";
}
```

?>

finally (my form) file name=login.php:

```
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
                        <table id="reg">
                        <th>Please the fill in the following:</th>
                            <tr><!--Username -->
                                <td>
                                    <p>Username:</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="username" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>Password:</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="password" name="pass1" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>Comfirm Password:</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="password" name="pass2" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>Email:</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="submit" name="register" />
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
```

Hope you guys help me !

Comment: There are two thing. Your php file name is inserdb where you write code for insert, but in your form action it is login .php? what it is? And in your insertdb page there is no assignment of POST data to any variable?

Comment: it's not going to affect.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you've posted, it doesn't look like you're ever capturing any of the data from the form. 
When you submit your form, it reloads login.php, and does nothing with the data just submitted. To access this data, in your login.php, use the [$_POST array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Once you take that $_POST data, you can then run the insertUser function.